# Uploading Files continuously to Firebase Storage in background with progress notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-notifications

I am able to upload images successfully to Firebase Storage but what if

- App is stopped,closed or killed by user or system ?
- Network is switched off ?
- or any other kind of failure condition.

Now what I want is to continue the task from same % uploaded in background until it finish and show its progress using notification at the top of screen how can I do this?

Here's what I want to show.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that you have to create a background service that will execute in the background and show the progress of the completion of the image. This link will help you.

```
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage
```

Just try to download the project and execute it you. Then you will get to know how it works and then by seeing the code you can implement in your app.